# 入れ子構造になったデータのクラスター分析がしたい

Tags: python, r

ただいま、国勢調査等のデータを使って地域差の分析をしています。
そのなかで、以下のように入れ子になったデータがセットを作成しました。ほとんどのデータは町丁目まであるのですが、統計によっては一部市区町村までしかないデータ（財政力指数など）があるため入れ子構造になっており、このデータを2層そのまま使ってクラスター分析を行いたいです。

このようなネストされたデータに適切なクラスタリング手法はないでしょうか？また、できればRかPythonで実装したいと考えております。
よろしくおねがいします。

**対象のデータセット例:**

```
市区町村, 町丁目, x1, x2...
A, a1, x1_A, x2_a1,
A, a2, X1_A, x2_a2,
A, a3, X1_A, x2_a3,
B, b1, X1_B, x2_b1,
B, b2, X1_B, x2_b2,
B, b3, X1_B, x2_b3,
```

Comment: どのような入れ子になっているのですか？
「対象のデータセット例」は、単純な２次元の表のCSV形式データのように見えるのですが。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。同じ市区町村のなかに各町丁目のデータが入っている状態です。たとえば、同じ行に市区町村レベルの値（財政力指数など）と、町丁目レベルの値（人口など）があります。マルチレベル分析のようなな2層構造を考慮したクラスタリングをしたいです。

Comment: 「同じ市区町村のなかに各町丁目のデータが入っている状態」って、どういう意味ですか？
"市区町村, 町丁目, x1, x2"といった項目が持つ意味、依存関係・入れ子関係、といったものを論理的な構造に整理しないと、理解不能のデータ（ゴミ！）から脱出できないのではないでしょうか。